# Why do NDSolve and OutputResponse not evaluate non-analytic functions numerically?

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

```
test = OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[1/(1 + s), s], Exp[-(1/t)], {t, 0, 10}]
```

does not evaluate.  If `Exp[-(1/t)]` is replaced by `Exp[-t]`, it's fine.

Starting the numerical evaluation at `t>0` does not help, either.  (v9.0.1.0 on Mac OS).  Thanks.

The same issue occurs with NDSolve:

```
NDSolve[{y'[t] + y[t] == Exp[-1/t], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

does not generate an interpolating function.  Replacing `Exp[-(1/t)]` by `Exp[-t]` does.

Comment: This behavior seems rather strange, and some suspicious messages are produced. Starting from `t == 1` doesn't help; changing `Exp[-1/t]` into `Exp[-1/(t + 1*^-10)]` does. Bug?

Comment: Thanks!  The `t` to `t + eps` trick does seem to work for both `OutputResponse` and `NDSolve`.

Comment: It probably should be noted that it does help to start from a value larger than zero for `NDSolve` (at least if one adopts the initial condition), but not for `OutputResponse`...

Answer (score 1):

This is just an observation and a workaround for now. Instead of using `OutputResponse` with `{t,0,limit}`, just use `t`.

This forces M to give an analytical solution using `DSolve` (not as fast as numerical with the limit, but it does avoid the problem you see with `t=0`. This is why `NDSolve` also fails, since when using the limit, `NDSovle` is used vs. `DSolve`

```
sol = First@OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[1/(1 + s), s], Exp[-(1/t)], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]